# Using the "pg" gem with Rails 3 ... why am I getting this error in Netbeans when I do a "bundle install"?

Tags: postgresql, netbeans, ruby-on-rails-3, rvm

At my wits end with this!

My current set up is:
- Ruby 1.9.2
- Rails 3.0.1
- pg (0.9.0)

My $PATH right now looks like this:

> /Users/fjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/fjones/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0@global/bin:/Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin:/Users/fjones/.rvm/bin:ARCHFLAGS=-arch
>   x86_64:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin:/Library/Glassfish/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin

Anytime I attempt to do a "bundle install" from Netbeans 6.9.1 I get the following exception.

> Installing pg (0.9.0) with native
>   extensions
>   /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:483:in
>   `rescue in block in build_extensions':
>   ERROR: Failed to build gem native
>   extension.
>   (Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError)
>
> /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
>   extconf.rb  checking for pg_config...
>   no
>
> ===========   WARNING   ===========
>        You are building this extension on OS X without setting the
>   ARCHFLAGS environment variable, and
>   pg_config wasn't found in    your
>   PATH. If you are seeing this message,
>   that means that the    build will
>   probably fail.
>
> If it does, you can correct this by
>   either including the path    to
>   'pg_config' in your PATH or setting
>   the environment variable    ARCHFLAGS
>   to '-arch ' before building.
>
> For example:   (in bash) $ export
>   PATH=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin:$PATH
>               $ export ARCHFLAGS='-arch x86_64'   (in tcsh) % set path = (
>   /opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin $PATH
>   )
>               % setenv ARCHFLAGS '-arch x86_64'
>
> Then try building again.
>
> =================================== 
>   MacOS X build: fixing architecture
>   flags: checking for libpq-fe.h... no
>   Can't find the 'libpq-fe.h header
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason,
>   probably lack of necessary libraries
>   and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log
>   file for more details.  You may need
>   configuration options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=/Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/ruby
>           --with-pg
>           --without-pg
>           --with-pg-config
>           --without-pg-config
>           --with-pg-dir
>           --without-pg-dir
>           --with-pg-include
>           --without-pg-include=${pg-dir}/include
>           --with-pg-lib
>           --without-pg-lib=${pg-dir}/lib
>           --enable-static-build
>           --disable-static-build
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.9.0
>   for inspection. Results logged to
>   /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.9.0/ext/gem_make.out
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:486:in
>   `block in build_extensions'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in`
>   each'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:446:in
>   `build_extensions'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/installer.rb:198:in`
>   install'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/source.rb:100:in
>   `install'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:55:in`
>   block in run'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in
>   `block in each'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in`
>   each'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:12:in
>   `each'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:44:in`
>   run'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/installer.rb:8:in
>   `install'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/cli.rb:221:in`
>   install'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/task.rb:22:in
>   `run'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:118:in`
>   invoke_task'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:246:in
>   `dispatch'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:389:in`
>   start'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.3/bin/bundle:13:in
>   `<top (required)>'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/bundle:19:in`
>   load'
>           from /Users/fjones/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/bundle:19:in
>   `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWER:

So this is really a problem with Netbeans 6.9.1 not assigning the correct path info for Ruby 1.9.2 gems.  The solution:

1. Go to Tools > Ruby Platforms
2. Select Ruby 1.9.2-p0 in the Platforms listbox
3. Update "Gem Home" and "Gem Path" based on what those paths *should* be (run "gem env" from Terminal to get that info)

This will actually fix a number of things in addition to being able to run "bundle install" with the pg gem.  In addition you'll be able to install the fast debugger for 1.9.2 and manage your other gems from within netbeans.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to install the development version of libpq (headers and libraries). Unfortunately I have no idea what exactly should be done on OS X.

Comment: Funny thing is that I can "sometimes" run "bundle install" from terminal ...buy I consistently get this problem in netbeans. Maybe it's time to switch back to textmate.